# Combining "like" rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table of locations_from, locations_to, and count of flights.  I want to combine the rows where departure on one row equals arrival on the other (for example LA TO NY combined with NY TO LA) and SUM the like rows.

I think it would be better explained with an example.

**BEFORE**

```
locations_from      locations_to      # of Flights
--------------------------------------------------
San Francisco, CA   Los Angeles, CA     29558
Los Angeles, CA     San Francisco, CA   32389
New York, NY        Los Angeles, CA     30389
Los Angeles, CA     New York, NY        35484
Las Vegas, NV       Los Angeles, CA     28363
Los Angeles, CA     Las Vegas, NV       34455
Honolulu, HI        Kahului, HI         46563
Kahului, HI         Honolulu, HI        16879
San Francisco, CA   New York, NY        44654
New York, NY        San Francisco, CA   25882
```

**AFTER**

```
From/To             From/To           # of Flights
---------------------------------------------------
San Francisco, CA   Los Angeles, CA      61947
New York, NY        Los Angeles, CA      65873
Las Vegas, NV       Los Angeles, CA      62818
Honolulu, HI        Kahului, HI          63442
San Francisco, CA   New York, NY         70536
```

I have tried a cross join on itself

```
where a.locations_from = b.locations_to
```

this works but I end up getting double the rows (IE one for LA TO NY and also one for NY TO LA)

Comment: Just to clarify, you just need the number of flights between 2 cities. The from/to city doesn't matter, correct?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: Can you add a table schema. I am basically looking for a primary key in your table. So basically besides the from, to and no of flights column, do you have a primary key column?

Answer (score 2):

Simply Use `CASE ... END` to "sort" the airports and then group by that "sorted" pair.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN [locations_from] > [locations_to]
           THEN [locations_to]
         ELSE
           [locations_from]
       END [From/To],
       CASE
         WHEN [locations_from] > [locations_to]
           THEN [locations_from]
         ELSE
           [locations_to]
       END [From/To],
       sum([# of Flights]) [# of Flights]
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY CASE
                  WHEN [locations_from] > [locations_to]
                    THEN [locations_to]
                  ELSE
                    [locations_from]
                END,
                CASE
                  WHEN [locations_from] > [locations_to]
                    THEN [locations_from]
                  ELSE
                    [locations_to]
                END;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/70a7d/3)

And here is also an alternative solution using a `FULL JOIN` on the opposite direction.

```
SELECT coalesce(t1.[locations_from], t2.locations_from) [locations_from],
       coalesce(t1.[locations_to], t2.locations_from) [locations_to],
       coalesce(t1.[# of Flights], 0) + coalesce(t2.[# of Flights], 0) [# of Flights]
       FROM elbat t1
            FULL JOIN elbat t2
                      ON t2.[locations_from] = t1.[locations_to]
                         AND t2.[locations_to] = t1.[locations_from]
       WHERE (t1.[locations_from] IS NULL
              AND t1.[locations_to] IS NULL
               OR t1.[locations_from] < t1.[locations_to])
             AND (t2.[locations_from] IS NULL
                  AND t2.[locations_to] IS NULL
                   OR t2.[locations_from] > t2.[locations_to]);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/70a7d/10)

Comment: @HABO: Works for me. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6d3c26/1) It gives me 84 = 42 + 42 flights in total. I don't see any fun.

Comment: Apologies, my bad. Apparently I can't read all the way across an output row.

Answer (score 2):

Using union

```
Declare @YourTable Table (SomeRowID int,[locations_from] varchar(50),[locations_to] varchar(50),[# of Flights] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'San Francisco, CA','Los Angeles, CA',29558)
,(2,'Los Angeles, CA','San Francisco, CA',32389)
,(3,'New York, NY','Los Angeles, CA',30389)
,(4,'Los Angeles, CA','New York, NY',35484)
,(5,'Las Vegas, NV','Los Angeles, CA',28363)
,(6,'Los Angeles, CA','Las Vegas, NV',34455)
,(7,'Honolulu, HI','Kahului, HI',46563)
,(8,'Kahului, HI','Honolulu, HI',16879)
,(9,'San Francisco, CA','New York, NY',44654)
,(10,'New York, NY','San Francisco, CA',25882);

select [locations_from], [locations_to], sum([# of Flights])
from 
(
select [locations_from], [locations_to], [# of Flights] 
from @YourTable 
where [locations_from] < [locations_to] 
union all
select [locations_to], [locations_from],  [# of Flights] 
from @YourTable 
where [locations_from] > [locations_to] 
) t
group by [locations_from], [locations_to]
```

Comment: Yup.  Even better. +1  However, one should <= or >= just in case of an emergency turn-around  NY to NY  :)

Answer (score 1):

Just another option using a `CROSS APPLY` and a conditional aggregation

This examples assumes you have some sort of RowID

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table (SomeRowID int,[locations_from] varchar(50),[locations_to] varchar(50),[# of Flights] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'San Francisco, CA','Los Angeles, CA',29558)
,(2,'Los Angeles, CA','San Francisco, CA',32389)
,(3,'New York, NY','Los Angeles, CA',30389)
,(4,'Los Angeles, CA','New York, NY',35484)
,(5,'Las Vegas, NV','Los Angeles, CA',28363)
,(6,'Los Angeles, CA','Las Vegas, NV',34455)
,(7,'Honolulu, HI','Kahului, HI',46563)
,(8,'Kahului, HI','Honolulu, HI',16879)
,(9,'San Francisco, CA','New York, NY',44654)
,(10,'New York, NY','San Francisco, CA',25882)

;with cte as ( 
    Select A.SomeRowID
          ,Loc1    = min(Loc)
          ,Loc2    = max(Loc)
          ,Flights = sum(Val)
     From  @YourTable A
     Cross Apply ( values ([locations_from],[# of Flights])
                         ,([locations_to]  ,0)
                 ) B (Loc,Val)
     Group By A.SomeRowID
) 
Select Loc1
      ,Loc2
      ,Flights=sum(Flights)
 From  cte
 Group By Loc1,Loc2
```

**Returns**

```
Loc1             Loc2               Flights
Honolulu, HI     Kahului, HI        63442
Las Vegas, NV    Los Angeles, CA    62818
Los Angeles, CA  New York, NY       65873
Los Angeles, CA  San Francisco, CA  61947
New York, NY     San Francisco, CA  70536
```